# collectionView nil when [self.collectionView reloadData] is called, reloadData not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I'm making an app that pulls images from both Flickr, and Imgur using their API.
After populating my model that stores the image URL and the title of the image, I want to reload the UI so that, the images populate the collectionview, but when its called, collectionview is nil.

This delegate method is called in the class responsible for fetching images using the APIs.

```
-(void)refreshUIOnMainThread
{
    photosFromWeb = [libraryAPI getPhotos];
    if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(reloadUIAfterImageDownload:)]) {
    [self.delegate reloadUIAfterImageDownload:photosFromWeb];
    }
}
```

The delegate method is defined in ViewController.m, the class where the UICollectionView delegate functions should be called upon a call to reloadData.

```
-(void)reloadUIAfterImageDownload:(NSArray*)photosFromWeb
{
    allPhotos = photosFromWeb;
    NSLog(@"reloadUIAfterDelegate: Number of Photos in Photo Model: %lu\n",   
    (unsigned long)[allPhotos count]);

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"about to reload collectionview...\n");
        //collectionview is nil, so reloadData is not called???????
        [self.collectionView reloadData]; 
    });

}
```

Originally I thought the photo Model array was 0, meaning 0 cells would populate.

```
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView    
 numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"numberofItemsInSection: Number of Photos in Photo Model: %lu\n",   
    (unsigned long)[allPhotos count]);
    return ([allPhotos count]);
}
```

but that's not the case.

```
NSLog(@"reloadUIAfterDelegate: Number of Photos in Photo Model: %lu\n", 
(unsigned long)[allPhotos count]);
```

returns a count of 128 indicating that Photo objects are there, and in the debugger I find the collectionview has a nil value within the delegate method definition. Why could this be?

Repo: https://github.com/danielv775/Flickr-Image-Gallery/tree/master/Photo%20Gallery
These functions are in FlickrClient.m and ViewController.m

Comment: Where do you set up your `collectionView` property? Is it ever not nil? I'm assuming this is a case of the `IBOutlet` not being connected.

Comment: I check in viewDidLoad, that it is not nil, it is set up as an IB outlet in viewController.h

Comment: Can you override the setter for your `collectionView` property? In it, you can first check if the new value is nil, and add a breakpoint for that case. Then you can see what's setting your property to nil. If you want, I can add the code for that as an answer.

Comment: Actually, I'm just going to clone your repo and see if I can figure it out locally.

Answer (score 1):

Ah I see the issue now. It lies in this line of `LibraryAPI.m`:

```
flickrClient = [[FlickrClient alloc]init];
vc = [[ViewController alloc]init];
flickrClient.delegate = vc;
```

You're creating a new instance of your view controller, so none of the IBOutlets are set up on this new instance. Instead, you need to set your delegate from `ViewController.m` like so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    LibraryAPI *libraryAPI = [LibraryAPI sharedInstance];
    libraryAPI.flickrClient.delegate = self;
}
```

This assumes you have a `flickrClient` property on your `LibraryAPI`. You could also add a delegate property on `LibraryAPI` if you wanted.

NOTE: You also want to change your delegate property on `flickrClient` like so:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <FlickrClientDelegate> delegate;
```

Delegates should not maintain strong references.